# VSCode ruby - autocomplete suggestions not showing when typing lowercase characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, visual-studio-code

I'm working on a Rails project in VsCode and the autocomplete feature does not work well for ruby - it autocompletes well if I type something starting with upper case letter only, lowercase usually dont get any autocomplete (unless it a lowcase var name with underscores) - here is a [screencast](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Pr7TlZWy9OPTGCeGCT-VYtcV_y20eKNL/view?usp=sharing) that shows that. I already tried disabling some extensions that might affect autocomplete (VSCode Ruby, Solargraph, Tabnine, Ruby), I also unchecked 'Snippets Prevent Quick Suggestions'. Any suggestions (ha!) how to fix this?